# Start an animation after page loads on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to make an element animate after the page loads on react, how do I do that please.

I'm new to react so I don't really know how to target the class and animation, but here is the

HTML and CSS

```
<div className="dangle" >
</div>
```

```
.dangle {
  animation: swing ease-out 5s forwards;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[link to codepen sample](https://codepen.io/Triciah101/pen/xxEEpGZ)

Please I need the solution in react please

Comment: you could define a 'componentDidMount' function to conditionally apply the `dangle` class

Comment: when i look at your codepen, it looks like it's working already... what's the problem with how it's working now?

Comment: @TKoL It happens before the page loads, so sometimes the animation is done before i get to see it.

Comment: @TKoL Please how do I do that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html - you make a stateful component and you write a `componentDidMount` function inside of it. Inside that function, you do something like `this.setState({dangle:true})`, and you make your rendered div have the class `dangle` conditionally based on `this.state.dangle`

Comment: You can do it using hooks; you are going to need `useRef` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) in order to create a reference to the `<div>` and `useEffect` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) in order to apply the animation after the component has been mounted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use "useState" to decide whether to apply animation. ( changing the state of the page )

Second, use "useEffect" to make the desired action run after the page loads. If you pass an empty array as the second parameter, the callback is executed only once after the page is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue; display:grid; place-items: center;}
    @keyframes swing {
      0% { transform: rotate(30deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(-30deg); }
    }
    .dangle {
      animation: swing ease-out 5s forwards;
      float: left;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {animate: false};
        }
        componentDidMount(){
          this.setState({animate: true})
        }
        
        render() {
          return <div className={this.state.animate ? "dangle" : ""}>Hello</div>;
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, What of if im using class component like componentDidMount(){
this.setState({dangle:true})
} how do I apply it here please

Comment: I changed code to class component. useEffect(callback, []) is similar to componentDidMount. read this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Answer (score 0):

You can add a load event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  for (let dangle of document.querySelectorAll(".dangle")) dangle.classList.add("loaded");
});
```

and enhance the CSS to be executed, make sure the CSS is to be executed only when it's loaded:

```
.dangle.loaded {
  animation: swing ease-out 5s forwards;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

and let's fix the HTML as well:

```
<div class="dangle" >
  foo
</div>
```

Comment: Please for react